# Proving collinearity of two points

Tags: geometry

Is there a way to prove that two points $P, Q$ are collinear using a method similar to that if points $A, B, C$ are collinear then $$\operatorname{area} \triangle ABC = \frac{1}{2}\begin{vmatrix}x_A & y_A & 1 \\ x_B & y_B & 1 \\ x_C & y_C & 1\end{vmatrix} = 0$$

I know that it is obvious that two points are collinear but I would just like to know if it can be proven in a way similar to this.

Comment: It's an axiom that any two distinct points lie in a common line in most settings. What do you mean by "proving" it?

Comment: Can you construct two points that are *not* collinear ?

Comment: There is no need to prove collinearity of two points , they are always collinear , problem can be asked for three points @DavisRash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Not in Euclidean geometry.  I can't comment on non-Euclidean geometry.

The method you mention for three points cannot be applied to two because with three points one can define an enclosed region of the plane and therefore find its area.  If the area is zero then the points are collinear.  This will not work with two points because two points are not enough to define an enclosed region of the plane.  So the concept of area won't make sense with only two points

There's another way.  We can show three points $P, Q, R$ are collinear by showing the vectors $\vec{PQ}$ and $\vec{PR}$ are parallel.  Note that this works in 2D and 3D.  This... also can't be carried over to two points $P$ and $Q$.  I suppose the best we could is to say that $P$ and $Q$ are collinear if and only if the vectors $\vec{PQ}$ and $\vec{PQ}$ are parallel.  But of course they are.. they're the same vector.  Or we could say if and only if $\vec{PQ}$ and $\vec{QP}$ are parallel.  And of course they are.  Each is $-1$ times the other.  I only bring this other method up to further illustrate how the notion of "proving collinearity" for two points doesn't really make sense.

And here's why - as mentioned in the comments on the question, the fact that two points are collinear is part of the [axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry#Axioms).  Specifically, axiom #1.  Axioms are statements and properties that are assumed to be true.  They're taken for granted.  There's nothing to prove.

Comment: Directing me to the axiom is perfect and provided what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

If think the best analoguous argument you make when you pass from three points to two points is the following:

Three points A,B,C **are collinear** iff the *area* of the triangle $\Delta_{ABC}$ is $0$.

Two points A,B **coincide** iff the *length* of the segment $AB$ is $0$.

And of course:

Four points A,B,C,D **are coplanar** iff the *volume* of the tetraedron $\Delta_{ABCD}$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The straight two-point analogue of the property would be in 1D,

$$\begin{vmatrix}x_A & 1 \\ x_B & 1 \end{vmatrix} = 0$$

and expresses that the two points are coincident (i.e. they don't define a line, just like three collinear points don't define a plane, four coplanar points don't define space...)

If you want a truly 2D expression, you can

- add any point along $AB$ (such as $A$, $B$ or the midpoint),

$$\begin{vmatrix}x_A & y_A & 1 \\ x_B & y_B & 1 \\ \frac{x_A+x_B}2 & \frac{y_A+y_B}2 & 1\end{vmatrix} = 0$$

- add a point of the line at infinity,
  $$\begin{vmatrix}x_A & y_A & 1 \\ x_B & y_B & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{vmatrix} = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Two points are always collinear, I presumed that you are asking the same question for 3 points

Then there are the following ways to prove it

1. Prove that the line joining 3 points make 180° angle
2. Prove that the area of triangle joining three points is 0
3. Let the points are A,B,C then prove that AB+BC=AC

All the mentioned things are actually same , but stated in different ways